# SignalR: Is it necessary to remove the connection id from group OnDisconnect()?

Tags: signalr

The tutorials only covered adding a connection ID to the group on `OnConnected()`, but what about cleaning it up on `OnDisconnect()`?

After a permanent loss of connectivity, a client is given a new connection ID. What happens to its old connection ID in the group list? Is it automatically cleaned up? or is it scalable enough that I don't have to worry about it?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

According to [the statement here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections#groups), you don't need to remove connections from groups:

> You should not manually remove the user from the group when the user
>   disconnects. This action is automatically performed by the SignalR
>   framework.

When a connection subscribes to a topic (which happens when you add the connection to a group), it receives a disposable which will remove the subscription when disposed (which means the connection isn't in the group anymore). This is triggered when a connection disconnects and is removed.